# Adjusting the color of multiple pictures at the same time in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, batch-processing, image-editing

Is there a way to adjust the color, hue, contrast, etc. at the same time in Photoshop?

I need to do a quick optimization on my pictures. For example, inserting 5 pictures at the same time and adjusting them.

Comment: Photoshop can do batch processing on multiple images, but not the way you describe. You can do it in Lightroom though.

Comment: Please do not call out to specific users for help. Besides that it's rude, it's useless as well: as long as a user hasn't posted anything in a Question thread, they won't see your mention. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

1. Adjust color, contrast & brightness using adjustment layers
2. Group it using a layer group
3. Drag & Drop the layer group to other documents

[image: Refer this screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Actions would be your best bet if you need to change a lot of them.

Open an image, or just a new canvas.

Open the Actions window from Window > Actions

Make a new action folder if you like, then create a new action by using the buttons at the bottom. Making sure the Record button in the action window is red, start creating adjustment layers and setting them to the levels you desire.

Perform a Save as using any file type you want to a common destination and then close the window (not photoshop, just the image). Do not change the filename of the file when saving you may do this later on in the process.

You should still be recording, so press the stop button. What you've just created is the action you'll use to change all of your photos.

Now under File > Automate > Batch..., pick the action folder and action that you just created.

Change the Source to be Folder to batch process all the files from a specific folder. You can also use Opened to apply this action to all tabs within Photoshop. If you have Adobe bridge you can start the batch process from Adobe bridge.

[image]

You may also change the File Naming tab in order to add things like Datestamps or sequence numbers. You can check Override Action "Save As" Commands, but it doesn't work for me since they always go to the folder i specified in the action.

When you press OK, Photoshop will open each of the files you specified for the source, apply the adjustment layers, save and then close it again before moving onto the next one. They do not close unless you specify it in the Action, which is why its important to include that step if you don't want photoshop to crash.

Answer (score 0):

If you know exactly what adjustments you require and they will be the same for each picture then an Automated Batch process would be your best option. Create a Macro and record all your adjustments save that Macro and then head on over to, File > Automate > Batch Select the macro you created with the folder of all your files and hit Ok.